# how to test history.push with RTL asynchronously in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

So, I was faced with a problem.
I tried to test functionality:
Click on a button to invoke async. function and on the end redirect to a new page.
The test below works if the invoked function is synchronous but in asynchronous case, I don't see expected changes.
So, what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the function:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

import { ROUTE_AUTHOR_LIST } from '../../constants';
import { createAuthor } from '../../services/authors';


const AuthorCreate = () => {
    const history = useHistory();

    const handleSave = async () => {
        const payload = ...
        await createAuthor(payload);
        history.push(ROUTE_AUTHOR_LIST);
    };


    return (
    <div>
        <Button variant="primary" onClick={ handleSave }>
          Save
        </Button>
    </div>
    );
}

export default AuthorCreate;
```

My test:

```
import React from "react";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import { createMemoryHistory } from "history";
import { Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { ROUTE_AUTHOR_LIST } from "../constants";

describe("Save button functionality", () => {
  test("redirect to correct URL", async () => {
    const history = createMemoryHistory();
    render(
      <Router history={history}>
        <AuthorCreate />
      </Router>
    );
    expect(
      screen.getByRole("heading", { name: /create author/i })
    ).toBeInTheDocument();

    const saveBtn = screen.getByRole("button", {
      name: /save/i,
      type: "button",
    });

    userEvent.click(saveBtn);

   // NOT PROPERLY WORKS
    expect(await history.length).toBe(2); 
    expect(await history.location.pathname).toBe(ROUTE_AUTHOR_LIST);
  });
```

Comment: Don't use RTL for react-testing-library because that shortcut mean [Right To Left in HTML](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=html%20RTL) the way to display text from the right in some languages. It's confusing. I suggest renaming the question to "how to test history.push asynchronously in react testing library" Because right now the question make no sense.

Comment: Try `(await history).length`?

Answer (score 0):

1. Is the asynchronous thing happening in createAuthor mocked correctly? So is your code ever reaching the `history.push` line in the test?
2. You can use [waitFor](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor) (from react-testing-library) to wait for asynchronous things in test. So for example
   `await waitFor(() => expect(history.length).toBe(2))`